# What's the difference between Render and GetHtml methods in DevExpress?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, devexpress

I would like to know whats the difference between using the method Render vs. using the method GetHtml, when using the DevExpress MVC Extensions? I know that GetHtml returns a MvcHtmString, and Render returns void, but I want to know what could be a practical difference to choose which one to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the DevExpress site, it looks like they now do the same thing:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q388623.aspx

> At present, the Render and GetHtml methods do the same thing: return a render string. Previously, the Render method wrote a render string to a Response directly. We have changed this behavior due to the following Breaking Change:

Comment: Thank you! I'm using DevExpress 2010 vol 2, so Render doesn't return a render string. However, considering the new functionality of the Render method, plus the issue mentioned in the above link, I guess it's better to use GetHtml.

Comment: On DevExpress 2011, the GetHtml method doesn't return an HTML string. It writes directly to the ViewContext.Writer: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B205547.aspx - It truly was a breaking change, as they called it, because it surely break my app when moving to 2011 edition :(

Answer (score 0):

They almost the same. while writing this I had to switch rendering a button on a form layout to Gethtml. trying to hide that button will work in a funky way using render. switching it to getHTML worked!